# SELECT query to fetch all last rows updated by last user when updated date is same

Tags: sql, select, oracle11g

I am using Oracle 11g database. 
Suppose I have a SQL table "Comments" with four columns. when some user comments, for each line of that comment, one row is being inserted into the table.

```
lineNo | Comment          | updatedDate     | UpdateBy
-----------------------------------------------------------
1      | Comment line 1   |  23-May-16      |   Abhi
2      | Comment line 2   |  23-May-16      |   Abhi
3      | Comment line 3   |  23-May-16      |   Rohit
4      | Comment line 4   |  23-May-16      |   Malay
5      | Comment line 5   |  23-May-16      |   Malay
6      | Comment line 6   |  23-May-16      |   Abhi
7      | Comment line 7   |  23-May-16      |   Abhi
8      | Comment line 8   |  23-May-16      |   Abhi
9      | Comment line 4   |  23-May-16      |   Abhi
```

I would like to write SELECT query to fetch all last rows updated by last user.  in above case LineNo 6,7,8 and 9 should be fetched. updated date is same.
I am having only read only access to database and can not add any new column to group updates.

Is there any way by which I can fetch these rows?

Comment: Why `1,2` are not selected? they're also updated by `Abhi` in the same date.

Comment: because I want only last rows updated by last user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Query will give the last comments the last commenter did, in your case 6/7/8/9

```
SELECT *
FROM "Comments"
WHERE "lineNo">
    ( SELECT max("line No")
     FROM "Comments"
     WHERE (UpdateBy,updatedDate)<>
         ( SELECT "UpdateBy","updatedDate"
          FROM "Comments"
          WHERE "lineNo"=
              (SELECT max("lineNo")
                   FROM "Comments") ))
```

Modified the Query so if the last commenter commented on 2 differents days (or more) it'll take into account the last commented day.

SqlFiddle here : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/91176e/1   (Mysql compatibility since Oracle fiddle are buggy for the time being)

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you want.

```
SELECT Comments.* 
FROM (SELECT MAX(lineNo) AS maxLineNo, Comment FROM Comments GROUP BY Comment) as X 
INNER JOIN Comments ON (Comments.lineNo = X.maxLineNo AND Comments.Comment = X.Comment)
```